# Excel 2010 Convert scientific notation equation in cell contents into decimal representation

Tags: excel, scientific-notation

I have a spreadsheet that has nearly 400 equations in it.  The creator of the spreadsheet copy/pasted the values from another source.  There are several that use scientific notation in their variable coefficients.  I am looking for a way to convert them into decimal notation so that I can store them in a database and execute using dynamic sql.

Here's an example of what I have

```
y = -6E-05x4 + 0.0272x3 - 1.4546x2 - 17.743x + 8137.3
```

I want it to be this

```
y = -0.00006x^4 + 0.0272x^3 - 1.4546x^2 - 17.743x + 8137.3
```

The column of equations is considered a "General" column by Excel.  I tried changing the column type, hoping that Excel would recognize the function and convert the coefficients, but it won't.  I am trying to not have to re-write all these equations manually converting the scientific notation.  I am also open to using a 3rd party piece of software to convert the scientific notation to decimal representation.

Comment: Are all of the equations polynomials? Is there a maximum number of terms in your equation? Are the polynomials always "in order" (x^4, then x^3, then x^2... etc)?

Comment: `y = -0.00006Ex^4 + ...` that E is a typo?

Comment: What have you tried? I would just split the parts and convert each part to a double using VBA.  You could probably do it with complex formulas.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, that was a typo.  It was fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 All of the equations are polynomials.  As of now they are all "in order", but since a human is inputting them, the best I can ask is that he makes sure they're all in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a VBA UDF (user defined function).
I

- use a regex to parse any numbers entered in Scientific notation
- convert them to decimal numbers
- replace the original value with the decimal value

Values greater than about 10^28 will be left unchanged.  Values less than about 10^-28 will be converted to a zero (0).

---

```
Option Explicit
Function ConvertToDecimal(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    'Regex pattern to extract Scientific numbers
    Const sPat As String = "[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?[Ee][+-]\d+"
    Dim sRepl As String, I As Long

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
            sRepl = S
            For Each M In MC
                On Error Resume Next
                    sRepl = Replace(sRepl, M, Format(CDec(M), "#,##0.0" & WorksheetFunction.Rept("#", 30)), 1, 1)
                    Select Case Err.Number
                        Case 6 'Overflow
                        'do nothing. sRepl is unchanged
                        Case Is <> 0
                            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
                            Stop 'stop to debug
                    End Select
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next M
    End If
End With

ConvertToDecimal = sRepl

End Function
```

Comment: This was a great start.  I added a 2nd pass through the converted strings that will create careted exponent notation.

Comment: @TychoBrahe Not sure what you mean by that, but I see the `E` after converted values shown originally in your question was a typo.  I have edited the code to remove that, and the output matches your **edited** example in your original question.

Comment: What I meant was your solution converted the E into decimal notation, however the exponentiation of the X wasn't happening.  I modified your UDF to also raise the X to its exponent (e.g. 0.012x4 becomes 0.012x^4)

Comment: @TychoBrahe That is odd.  If the exponentiation operator is in the original, as it is in your example; it was retained in the result.  What happened with your real data?

Comment: The real data is created by a human being copy/pasted from excel.  The excel formula uses superscript which did not make the transfer during the copy/paste.  Adding in the caret is just another step in cleaning the equations for use.  Looking at my original post I included the carets, but that must have been taken from a translation-in-progress I had been doing.

Comment: @TychoBrahe Is it from a trendline equation on a graph?

Comment: Yes, a co-worker (non programmer) was tasked with creating the equations and getting them to me.  I'm tasked with writing a program to evaluate them, but the biggest hurdle is converting them into something that I can evaluate.

Comment: @TychoBrahe Those formulas will not be accurate unless he formats the label to show all (15) decimal places.